# C# how to show only one entry in a xml document?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, weather

I have a problem with my code: I want only to show the temperature from the XML returned from http://openweathermap.org/

```
namespace SMirror
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblWeather.Text = GetFormattedXml(CurrentUrl);
        }

        private const string API_KEY = "8b1ed1ebf1481ecf201d05b2feeca87d";
        private const string CurrentUrl = 
            "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?" +
            "q=Berlin&mode=xml&units=imperial&APPID=" + API_KEY;
        private const string ForecastUrl =
            "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?" +
            "q=Berlin&mode=xml&units=imperial&APPID=" + API_KEY;

        // Return the XML result of the URL.
        private string GetFormattedXml(string url)
        {
            // Create a web client.
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                // Get the response string from the URL.
                string xml = client.DownloadString(url);

                // Load the response into an XML document.
                XmlDocument xml_document = new XmlDocument();
                xml_document.LoadXml(xml);

                // Format the XML.
                using (StringWriter string_writer = new StringWriter())
                {
                    XmlTextWriter xml_text_writer =
                    new XmlTextWriter(string_writer);
                    xml_text_writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    xml_document.WriteTo(xml_text_writer);

                    // Return the result.
                    return string_writer.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your `GetFormattedXml` to be as following:

```
    private string GetFormattedXml(string url)
    {
        // Create a web client.
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            // Get the response string from the URL.
            string xml = client.DownloadString(url);

            // Load the response into an XML document.
            XmlDocument xml_document = new XmlDocument();
            xml_document.LoadXml(xml);

            return xml_document.SelectSingleNode("/current/temperature").Attributes["value"].Value;
        }
    }
```

and then you can rename it to `GetTemperature`

Comment: @user7371443 If this fixed your problem then kindly mark it as the answer.

Comment: But the return type is string so it cant return the Attribute. Any idea ?

Comment: @user7371443 Get the `Value` from the attribute and return that.

Comment: @BrianRogers yeah but how :) (Im pretty new to c#)

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni thanks a lot it works now. Have a nice day

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni Im sorry but I have another little question. If I want to display not only the temp. but the Country(for example) too ? How do I do that ?

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni I mean I cant return two values right ? And if I can would you show me please :)

Comment: Edit the function to return a string array `string[]` and use `xml_document.SelectSingleNode("/current/city/country").Value`to get the second value so the return value will be as:
`return new string[] { xml_document.SelectSingleNode("/current/temperature").Attributes["value"].Value, xml_document.SelectSingleNode("/current/city/country").Value};`

Comment: @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni And how do I call it later ? Because if I call the method like this: ´GetTemperature(CurrentUrl)´ I get a NullReferenceExeption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XPath query to select the `temperature` node, and then get the value of the `value` element.

```
XmlNode node = xml_document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/current/temperature");
string current_temperature = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value;
```